# Filtering English words with specific length

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list (from a pandas column: `df['Text'].tolist()`:

```
my_list=[came',
 'ป้องกัน',
 'moreover',
 'sah',
 'esketamine',
 'accredited',
 'condition',
 'tailored',
 'acts',
 'terms',
 "'",
 'البارد',
 'demonstrate',
 'amidst',
 'atotxa',
 'design',
 'ante',
 'ebsite',
 'problems',
 'oncosomes',
 'gradient',
 'tenable',
 'processing',
 'elemental',
 'card',
 'spreads',
 'मंत्रालय',
 'airlines',
 'desde',
 'retains',
 'n',
 '–',
 'ты']
```

I would like to keep only words greater than 2 and which are in English.
What I tried is as follows:

-apply a filter for words having length > 2:

```
new_corpus = list( map(lambda words: list(filter(lambda word: len(word)> 2, words)), my_list))
```

-then apply `detect()` for each element in the list:

```
 def det(x):
            lang = detect(x)
            return lang

 new_corpus.apply(det)
```

The problem is that with the first code I get all [] (empty elements), so I cannot apply any `detect` function to the list.

My expected output would be:

```
my_list=[came',
 'moreover',
 'sah', # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'esketamine',
 'accredited',
 'condition',
 'tailored',
 'acts',
 'terms',

 'demonstrate',
 'amidst',    # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'atotxa',    # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'design',
 'ante',
 'ebsite',    # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'problems',
 'oncosomes', # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'gradient',
 'tenable',
 'processing',
 'elemental',
 'card',
 'spreads',
 'airlines',
 'desde',      # it depends on detect function, if it selects this element as English or not
 'retains'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [list comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) This allows for the entire logic to be boiled down to a single line. An implementation may be:

```
new_corpus = [word for word in my_list if len(word) > 2 and detect(word)]
```

Additionally, this method *could* be used to create the filtered list from the dataframe directly. An implementation could be:

```
new_corpus = [word for word in df['Text'].tolist() if len(word) > 2 and detect(word)]
```

This does not, however, allow `df['Text'].tolist()` to be accessed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you to both for your answer as both work great. I would like to suggest one thing, @bbnumber2: it is possible to get error using detect because of the length of word. So probably it would be better to switch detect and len in your code. In this way, the code will run with no errors ;)

Comment: Just another thing: does it automatically detect 'en' as language? it works, but I would like to understand if it is automatically and/or if I need to do anything to change/detect a different language

Comment: @still_learning That would depend on your implementation of the `detect()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
cond1 = df['Text'].str.len()>=2
cond2 = df['Text'].map(detect)=='en'

df_sub = df[cond1 & cond2]
#df.loc[cond1 & cond2, 'Text'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BEN_YO. I chosen the other answer just because I found it more similar to what I was trying to do. But also yours works great and use a different approach. Thanks